# What is the cross domain issue

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

If I asked a stupid question here, Please don't laugh at me .

I have being heard `Cross Domain Issue` many times, But not really get involved in it in real case. So I searched it in the google. But found many posts are talking about `The cross domain issue when make a ajax call`. Not found even a post to tell about what exactly cross domain issue is, and why the cross domain is not allowed? and more question is if I say the cross domain issue, does it mean I made a wrong ajax request to different domain? Any other cases would cause this issue? Thanks.

The posts I read are

[How do I send a cross-domain POST request via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript)

["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-w)

Comment: Better search : ["Same Origin Policy"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: `:)` Joe, I didn't laugh, but the smiley did!

Comment: :) Amit, I hope you have a nice day.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a security restriction that prevents requests being made from one origin to another.

For example, it will prevent an `https://` page hitting an `http://` address because the protocol is different.

It will stop `example.com` calling `another.com` because it is a different domain.

It will stop `www.example.com` calling `subdomain.example.com` because it is a different sub domain.

And it will stop `example.com:80` calling `example.com:8080` because it is a different port.

It is possible to make cross-origin requests either using JSONP (if you trust the server!) or using a CORS request (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing), which both client and server must agree to (I can supply more details if you need it on this).

Comment: +1 Please give me more details (if some example will be fine)on it . Appreciated it !

Comment: CORS involves the client sending a pre-flight request to ask the server if it will allow the communication. The server then must respond with what origins it will talk to. There are exact details here: http://enable-cors.org/

Answer (score 2):

1.what exactly cross domain issue is & not allowed : it is because same-site origin policy which blocks Web pages from accessing data from another domain. **for information assurance**, javascript is limited to send request from one to another.

2.A cross domain request is not a wrong one. you may deal with it by some methods,like jsonp.

this link is about jsonp:
[Jsonp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)

---

Comment: JSONP is mostly obsolete now. The right way to deal with same origin policy is by setting the correct CORS headers.