# How to embed div/section of one website

Tags: jquery, iframe, embed

```
<html>
<head>
<script  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>    

<div id="target-div"></div>
<div id="error"></div>
<div id="success"></div>

<script>

//$('#target-div').load('https://example.com.au');

$( "#success" ).load( "https://example.com.au #divId", function( response, status, xhr ) {
    $( "#success" ).html( response );
  if ( status == "error" ) {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
  }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I get this response

Sorry but there was an error: 0 error

I tried  `<iframe>` but whole website get load with `<iframe>` while I just need to load particular section , I tried "`<iframe>` with div id but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely won't get this to run the way you imagine because of a cross-domain issue see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23927967/342840)